# Same packagename different signature

Tags: android, push, registration, google-cloud-messaging

First state, application is signed by debug certificate, and registered to GCM. Then my GCM connection server can send push message to my application.

Second state, application, which is the same packagename and application, is signed by release certificate. My app can register to GCM and can i send push message to application by using my GCM connection server? Is there any constrait?

Comment: What happens if you try to send push messages to your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package name and keystores should be same for Google Play. Not GCM. You could use package name and different keystore. No problem. AFAIK, GCM won't mind if you give same package name in any number of Google Projects. Because one app can have more than one GCM projects I believe.

Comment: thanks your answer, but i wonder something also. What kind of information(packagename, signature etc.) hold on GCM registration id  or how is it created by GCM? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. You might have to contact Google Engineers for that :)